Wiremock sends 404 error for HEAD request
I'm having a file correctly served by wiremock standalone, located in a subdirectory of __files, via an http GET request sent by curl:
Curl -XGET http://wiremockserver/api/file/myfile.json
So myfile.json located in __files/api/files.
So far so good.
Then, I run exactly the same http request, but just changing the GET method into a HEAD one using --head curl parameter: Wiremock sends a 404 although it should have returned a 200 ok with the headers only.
Any explanation for that ?
Thanks
Expect an http 200 ok instead of a 404 for a HEAD request

Did you configure wiremock to respond to the HEAD request, or just GET?  Also can you post some code/config about how you've got wiremock setup?

I think this is because when the HEAD request came through to WireMock it tried to match it against a stub which didn't exist so it returned a 404.  You should be able to verify this by looking at the WireMock logs and seeing if there is a non matched diff report.
Instead of relying on WireMocks ability to return files from the __files directory, it might be better to setup stubs for both the GET and the HEAD requests.
Something like this might work.  If you move your myfile.json into the __files folder and then setup your stubs like the following:
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "request" : {
        "urlPath" : "/api/file/myfile.json",
        "method" : "GET"
      },
      "response" : {
        "status" : 200,
        "bodyFileName" : "myFile.json"
      }
    },
    {
      "request" : {
        "urlPath" : "/api/file/myfile.json",
        "method" : "HEAD"
      },
      "response" : {
        "status" : 200,
        "bodyFileName" : "myFile.json"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Then with this example myFile.json:
{
  "hello": "world"
}

You should be able to send curl requests to both:
curl http://localhost:8080/api/file/myfile.json
{
  "hello": "world"
}

curl --head http://localhost:8080/api/file/myfile.json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Matched-Stub-Id: 3a6b3bfd-45a3-4ea4-b9e3-ce59b1b23866
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

If you wanted you could also setup a single stub with a method of ANY or GET_OR_HEAD

Hi, thanks a lot for the answer ! Anyway,  I'm surprised by the HEAD answer concerning the content-encoding header set to chunk : as for the GET, I would like Wiremock not use the chunk encoding, but rather use the classical content-length: is there a way, in the stub structure, to force the use of content- length rather than chunk encoding ? Of course, I do not want to set the content- length header explicitly, since I do not know the value to set ( length of the "myfile.json" file). Thanks again.

That is a good question.  I am not sure at this point why chunked was chosen.  I would need to look into this and see if this is WireMock code doing this or Jetty

I also realised today that there is a GET_OR_HEAD method that can be used.  I will update the answer

I have checked the code and it looks like WireMock uses chunk encoding by default.  This can be turned off using the --use-chunked-encoding option: Set the policy for sending responses with Transfer-Encoding: chunked. Valid values are always, never and body_file. The last of these will cause chunked encoding to be used only when a stub defines its response body from a file.
